# Sending data from Activity 2 to Activity 1 Fragment

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` on `Activity2` and whenever a `Button` is clicked I have to send what is written in the `EditText` to a certain `Fragment` of another `Activity1`.

I tried to send the data from the `Activity2` to `Activity1` but then I have to send it again from the `Activity1` to the `Fragment`.
Is there any way to send the data directly from `Activity2` to `Fragment` in the `Activity1`?

Comment: you have to pass it to the activity containing that fragment and from that activity to the fragment .

Comment: Add a bit of clarification. How do you received data from Activity 2 to Activity 1, by using onActivityResult()? Or by using arguments passed through an intent ?

Comment: Without **Activity1** there is no existence of Fragment. So, How can you bypass **Activity1**?

Comment: @MohamedAbdelraZek that's what i have already done, my question was if it was possible to pass data directly from Activity 2 to the Fragment

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov I passed arguments through an intent, and it worked, now i just want to skip a step and get the data directly to the Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an interface in your `Activity2`:

```
 public interface OnEditTextData{
            public void sendEdtData(String str);
        }
```

and Attach the `interface` in it's `oncreateView()`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

            try{
                mFragment fragment = new mFragment();
                onEditTextData= (OnEditTextData) fragment ; \\ update this line
            }catch(ClassCastException ex){

                Log.e("Activity2","error"+ ex);
            }
        }
```

then init your interface method :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 onEditTextData.sendEdtData(editText.getText().toString()); 
            }
        });
```

then implements Your `Fragment` from Activity2.OnEditTextData `interface` :

```
public class mFragment extends Fragment implements Activity2.OnEditTextData {
.
.
.


    @Override
        public void sendEdtData(String str) {
            // use your string
        }

}
```

Comment: How **Activity2** get **mFragment** context when `mFragment` attach with **Activity1**?

Comment: I get a NullPointerException when calling sendEdData on my EditText.toString() even if i checked the string is not null

Comment: @mohammadRezaAbiri `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.xxx.Activity2$OnEditTextData.sendEdtData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`                                                                                                  I also get `error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.Activity2 cannot be cast to com.xxx.Activity2$OnEditTextData`

Comment: @JacK'o'Lantern I updated my answer for resolve ClassCastException!

Comment: Thanks you very much @mohammadRezaAbiri , now it works :)

Comment: @mohammadRezaAbiri  upvoted it so I dont know , maybe someone else downvoted (anyway my vote wont appear because I only have 13 reputation score)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intent with startactivityforresult method also from fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}.
```

or you can use a static variable you can declare inside activity 1 and change its value from activity b and access from fragment.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use shared preference if you want the simple way, but not recommended though